# I am getting error while maximazing the chrome window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing the problem while executing the code to maximize the window.
Below is the error message:

```
unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.03 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'SDN-117', ip: '172.10.189.52', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed), userDataDir=C:\Users\TANUJA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9140_12941}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 12757c3f618b72bfaffb8713a175d458
```

Kindly help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: Try updating your chrome driver.  Your're using 2.25 and the latest version is 2.30

Comment: 1 month back i have execute the same code for same driver but that time it was working fine

Comment: Can you include the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To maximize Google Chrome browser window it is recommended to use `ChromeOptions` class instead of `driver.manage().window().maximize();`. Here is the sample code for your reference:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.